# XOR number combinations

Tags: algorithms

Assume we have some (for example 10 different) 8 bit numbers and a specific target number (also 8 bit) is there an efficient algorithm to find out which and if any combination of source numbers XORed together result in the target number. And if there are multiple solutions.

How could I solve such problems (without trying all possible combinations) and is there a name for this kind of problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related StackOverflow question: [Speed up processing 32 bit numbers in combinations (k from n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758136/speed-up-processing-32-bit-numbers-in-combinations-k-from-n)

Comment: Looks like it's similar to well-know Generalised birthday problem, but for one list.
See: https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2002/24420288/24420288.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and as it turns out there is no faster way than trying all possible combinations. The problem is an NP-hard problem. Here is an Wikipedia article basicly describing the same problem (and possible solutions): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: That problem is not the same; having XOR rather than $+$ makes a huge difference. Henning Makholm's answer is correct, and shows that your original problem is in P.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime having XOR instead of + makes only one difference in my opinion: that for a large set of random numbers, a humongous number of solutions (combinations) is expected to exist. So finding a solution should be relatively easy. But if you are given a large set of numbers that are carefully selected so that only one combination exists, finding this combination would be very very hard.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias read hmakholm's answer. In particular, as he says, if you have a large set of numbers, the set of winning combinations must also be large, unless it is empty.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime hmakholm's answer is beyond my level of knowledge in mathematics. I am coming here from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758136/) StackOverflow question, where it has been trivially demonstrated how easy it is to create a large set of numbers with zero solutions. Just make sure that one bit of the XORed sum is 1, and the same bit of all the numbers in the set is 0. It is less trivial to create a large set with a single solution though. If you are up for a challenge, I could attempt to create such a set, for your own solving pleasure. :-)

Comment: @EspeciallyLime, is it the same as https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43956/is-weighted-xor-sat-np-hard

Comment: @DmitryT No, because that question is asking about a weighted version, where you have to find the "cheapest" solution, not just any solution. The question we are discussing is essentially the standard (unweighted) version, and as the question you link to says, "the standard XOR-SAT problem is in P".

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure if this is the best way to solve your problem, but this is the way I would do it. I would go through all the numbers in given set and XOR every one of them with the target number. If the result of this operation is also in the given set then those two numbers make one pair which XORed results in the target number. I hope that was somewhat clear.

Comment: That's a nice way to find out if there are two numbers that do the job. Note that if you get $0$ the target number was in the set. To check for three you could use the numbers you get this way as a new group of targets to try to match from the the original set, and so on.

Comment: My concrete numbers are just examples. In practice the set will be greater than 100 and the result will almost always be a combination of at least 20 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Viewing your $n$-bit numbers as *bit vectors*, they form a *vector space* over $\mathbb F_2$ (the field with two elements) -- addition is binary XOR, and multiplication is binary AND.

Viewed, this way, you have a number of vectors and want to express a given vector as a *linear combination* of the given ones. Your specification is an XOR of some of the given vectors, but XOR is just a *sum* in this vector space, and since the only possible nonzero coefficient in $\mathbb F_2$ is $1$, a sum is *the same as* a linear combination.

This means that what you have is just a standard linear vector/matrix equation over $\mathbb F_2$, and standard techniques from *linear algebra*, such as Gaussian elimination, will work.

If you have $10$ original vectors, since that is more than $8$, ordinary linear algebra tells us that there will always be either no solutions, or more than one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know any terms for this class of problem. Since XOR behaves slightly differently than addition, it is possible to break up the problem and make it solvable more easily than brute-force by focusing on one bit at a time.

Create a storage array at least the size of your bit-width; values will be stored in the array such that the n-th element (in a 1-indexed array) has the n-th bit as its most-significant bit (MSB). For each of the inputs (I'll refer to them ask masks), see if a value is stored with the same MSB set, and if so, XOR the values; this will clear out the MSB and result in a smaller number. Continue until no numbers stored have the same MSB set, then store the number. Numbers that result in a zero from this operation are redundant (eg with 13 and 5 stored, 8 is redundant since 8 = 13 xor 5).

Below is an implementation in Python 3 to see if it is possible to obtain a target given a number of masks. It does not currently report which of the input masks were used as the current version doesn't retain them. [Try it on repl.it](https://repl.it/HsFr/0)

```
def xor_combo(target, mask_list):
    masks_by_bit = [0] * 8 # number of bits
    # use defaultdict(int) for arbitrary size

    for mask in mask_list:
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length
        while masks_by_bit[mask.bit_length() - 1] != 0:
            mask ^= masks_by_bit[mask.bit_length() - 1]
        if mask != 0:
            masks_by_bit[mask.bit_length() - 1] = mask
        # else: redundant mask

    while masks_by_bit[target.bit_length() - 1] != 0:
        target ^= masks_by_bit[target.bit_length() - 1]
    return (target == 0)
```

Example output:

```
xor_combo(5, [7, 2])
```

True : since 5 = 7 xor 2

```
xor_combo(5, [7, 3, 4])
```

False : since no combination 7, 3, and 4 can be combined via xor to give 5

```
xor_combo(5, [7, 3, 1])
```

True : since 5 = 7 xor 3 xor 1